# How do I track Ace in Sleeping Dogs?

Tags: sleeping-dogs

I am stuck in this bit of Sleeping Dogs - trying to track Ace.

Online videos such as [this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mlo3raiRexM) are not helping.

I would appreciate clear guidance on what needs to be done to win this bit.

Answer (score 5):

First, you'll need to position yourself in a way that will let you
triangulate the call. You need to drive until you are in the
middle of three points. These three points are not actually
given to you; just drive until you are in the middle of the
triangle on your cell phone.

Then, you'll be given a bunch of regions. Move around all of
them and find the region that has 3-4 green bars. This
indicates it has a strong enough signal for you to trace Ace.
Finally, you'll see the region zoomed in. There will be a
number of person symbols and cell phone tower icons,
indicating antennae. Cycle through the antennae; each one will
light up a different selection of people. (You may have to wait a
second or so to see all of them.) You want to find the person
icon that is lit up by all of the antennae.

Here's a trick to finding the common person:

1. Pick an antenna to start with, such as the southernmost
   one.
2. Focus on one specific person icon.
3. Cycle through each antenna, continuing to focus on
   that spot. Note whether the person icon appears again
   or not.
4. If you cycle through all of them and the person
   appears, then that is the right one. Move the crosshairs
   to it and select it.
5. If any antenna does not show that person, cycle back
   to the first antenna and return to step 2, choosing a
   different person icon.

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll need to position yourself in a way that will let you triangulate the call. You need to drive until you are in the middle of three points. These three points are not actually given to you; just drive until you are in the middle of the triangle on your cell phone.

Then, you'll be given a bunch of regions. Move around all of them and find the region that has 3-4 green bars. This indicates it has a strong enough signal for you to trace Ace.

Finally, you'll see the region zoomed in. There will be a number of person symbols and cell phone tower icons, indicating antennae. Cycle through the antennae; each one will light up a different selection of people. (You may have to wait a second or so to see all of them.) You want to find the person icon that is lit up by all of the antennae.

Here's a trick to finding the common person:

1. Pick an antenna to start with, such as the southernmost one.
2. Focus on one specific person icon.
3. Cycle through each antenna, continuing to focus on that spot. Note whether the person icon appears again or not.
4. If you cycle through all of them and the person appears, then that is the right one. Move the crosshairs to it and select it.
5. If any antenna does not show that person, cycle back to the first antenna and return to step 2, choosing a different person icon.